# How to use configuration files with .Net Core 3.1 Unity Framework

Tags: .net-core, unity-container, asp.net-core-3.1

In the days of app.config/web.config, it was possible to use Xml Configuration within the config file to configure the Unity Framework.  Is there still some way to do that moving forward into the .Net Core 3.1 & 5.0 world?  If so, might someone provide a good example and documentation on it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is still possible, Create an app.config that specifies the where your unity container config file is:

```xml
<configSections>
  <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration"/>
</configSections>
<unity configSource="unity.config" />
```

They are working on supporting json and .net core directly, but that’s for the future.